# Run batch file in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

How can I run a batch from from within vb.net?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the Process class to run a batch file

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("Path TO Batch File")
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.CreateNoWindow = False
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
psi.UseShellExecute = False

Dim process As Process = Process.Start(psi)
```

Comment: Thanks, It's better to add    psi.WorkingDirectory = "PATh TO Dir" as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple and straight forward method:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\batch.bat")
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the `Process.Start` and pass the path to the batch file

```
Process.Start(pathToBatchFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way if you know the exact location of the file is

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\test\file.bat")
```

In Visual Studio the file must exist in the `/bin/debug` or `/bin/release` depending on your current build configuration

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("test.bat")
```