# Wait for batch file to close before continuing - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run a batch file via VB and I need to wait for it to complete/exit before progressing.  The issue I believe I am having is that when a batch file is executed, it opens cmd.exe and not the batch file.

This is what I am executing with VB

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\PingCheck\machines.txt")
    FileCopy(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\machines.txt", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\PingCheck\machines.txt")

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\PingCheck\go.bat")
    psi.RedirectStandardError = True
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    psi.CreateNoWindow = False
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.UseShellExecute = False

    Dim process As Process = process.Start(psi)
    process.WaitForExit()

    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 2
    FileCopy(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\PingCheck\machines.txt", My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\machines.txt")
    'My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ping.bat")
    MsgBox("Ping Check Complete")
```

The problem im having is that it will just delete ping.bat before it completes.
How do I go about monitoring the process from the batch file I call. Then once it exits, continue with the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RHicke shows a nice example of how to run a batch process in VB.NET here, [Run batch file in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net).

To expand, you should use the function WaitForExit() to wait for the process to complete.

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("Path TO Batch File")
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.CreateNoWindow = False
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
psi.UseShellExecute = False

Dim process As Process = Process.Start(psi)

process.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Thanks, however im not convinced this is working.

I've tweaked my script to match this, however it still shows the MessageBox before it appears to have finished.  See first post

Comment: Im telling it to run \PingCheck\go.bat and before it completes it shows the message box.

The go.bat actually runs and sets of a loop of ping tests so it doesn't close until these are complete

Comment: i just did a quick test with a batch file that just runs a ping on a bad address (so it takes about 15-20 seconds), and it waited until the ping completed before showing me the message box. can you edit your question to include the batch code (if it isn't crazy long)?

Comment: The batch file is ridiculously complex (I didn't write it)
I'm also trying to see if I can do a ping test using VB instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096539/pinging-a-list-of-machines-in-vb-net

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to start the batch file. The process reference will give you access to the property HasExited (and more interesting information). The HasExited property indicates whether a process has completed.

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                                {
                                    FileName = "batch file path",
                                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    Arguments = "parameters if applicable",
                                    CreateNoWindow = true
                                });

while(!process.HasExited)
{
    // obviously do some clever here to wait 
}
```

Code is in C# but the principle should work in VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar before.  This code invokes RoboCopy from within VB.Net, using the System.Diagnostics.Process (mentioned by rivethead_).

```
Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()

proc.EnableRaisingEvents = False
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "d:\robocopy\robocopy"
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = strSrcDir & " " & strDestDir & " " & strFile & " " & My.Settings.robocopyFlags
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
```

Otherwise, what is the ping.bat doing?  Is it just doing a "ping" command?  If so, maybe you could invoke that with a System.Diagnostics.Process (instead of invoking a .bat file to do it).  That might give you some more control over your process.

Comment: The ping.bat actually loops itself so I believe what may be happening is that the original ping.bat closes after opening another copy.  As I didn't write the batch file and it is insanely complicated I am unable to tell :(