# Pinging a list of machines in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of machines, 1 per line in a file called devices.txt.

What I need to be able to do is to ping each of these machines, and then output each machine that is online to another text file called machines.txt

The files need to just be the machine name and have 1 machine per line.

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed.  Got the right answer first time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    Sub main()

    Dim results As New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)

    Using myReader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("c:\AllComputerNames.txt")

        Do While myReader.Peek() >= 0
            Dim computerName As String = myReader.ReadLine

            Debug.WriteLine(computerName, "Pinging computer :")

            results.Add(computerName, My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName))

        Loop

    End Using

End Sub
```

Edit or if you want to write it to file :

```
        Using writer = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\ComputersOutput", False)

        Using myReader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("c:\AllComputerNames.txt")

            Do While myReader.Peek() >= 0
                Dim computerName As String = myReader.ReadLine

                Debug.WriteLine(computerName, "Pinging computer :")

                writer.WriteLine(String.Join(" - ", computerName, My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName)))

            Loop

        End Using

    End Using
```

Comment: I've done Call main, however it errors out

    System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException: An exception occurred during a Ping request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

Comment: Sounds like either you're passing a funny computer name (check your immediate window) or theirs a problem with your network. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwfshz0y.aspx

Comment: I've passed it a set of random names and one that will work such as 123412d.  That isn't a valid machine name but if I ping it manually it will not connect as expected

Comment: Apologies, had a typo in a machine name!  That script executes, however how do I get it to output the pingable machines to another file?

Comment: I've now updated my answer so that it will also write it out

Comment: Hmm, I am now getting
 Error 6 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Join' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I also understand that will output "Machine A - False".  Is there anyway to only output machine names only where the machine is pingable?

Comment: Yep just move the "My.Computer.Network.Ping(computerName)" into an IF and only call "writer.WriteLine()" if its true.