# Unable to execute bat file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an exe vb.net application and a bat file located in the same drive in different folders. Шhen I try to execute the bat file, it is executing properly.
**Problem occurs when I try to execute the file using the code**. It is just opening the bat file and not executing the code written inside the bat file.

I tried different Codes:

**Code # 01:**

```
    Shell(path, AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True)
```

**Code # 02:**

```
    Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "/encryptdaemon.bat"

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(path)
    psi.RedirectStandardError = True
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    psi.CreateNoWindow = False
    psi.LoadUserProfile = True
    psi.Verb = "Open"


    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.UseShellExecute = False

    Dim process As Process = process.Start(psi)

    process.WaitForExit()
```

**Code # 03:**

```
    Dim objProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
        Try
            objProcess = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\GenericEncryption_Client\\encryptdaemon.bat"
            objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal


            objProcess.Start()

            'Wait until the process passes back an exit code 
            objProcess.WaitForExit()

            'Free resources associated with this process
            objProcess.Close()
        Catch
            ' MessageBox.Show("Could not start process " & ProcessPath, "Error")
        End Try
```

None of the above codes work for me. It is just calling bat and suddenly gets invisible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it throws any error or exceptions?

Comment: Add `pause` at the end of the .bat file and try again.

Comment: no it dost not throw exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net ?