# How Do I Launch a Bat in Visual Studio via a Button

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I wrote up a VERY simple batch file (with your guys' help) that allows a user to terminate the session when they are remoted into another user. The batch file currently just asks for the Session ID and then kills the session. I am trying to clean it up though by creating a simple little Visual Studio Program. So far all I have managed is to create a button, and the text field that will be needed to enter the session ID. At this point, I just need a hand actually applying the action to the button. Is there an easy way to do this with my already created batch file or no?
To clarify: I need a script or a way to implement my batch file to my button.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run batch file in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net)

Comment: Ideally you would use vb or c to replace your batch file.  That being said, please see the linked duplicate question for a few ways to run your existing bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called callbatch.c with this code

```
#include <cstdlib>
int your_function()
{
system("call BATCHFILE.bat");
return 0;
}
```

Then, in your Button On Click code type:

```
your_fuction();
```

And don't forget about typing on top of the file where the button code is:

```
#include <callbatch.c>
```