# Check for new files at program start

Tags: vb.net

I need to write a .dll for a program that works with some files.

I need to code that every time someone starts the program, it should check in a folder for new files and if there are new ones, it should copy them automatically in the programs folder and restart the program. If there are none the program should just start normally.

My problem is that I dont know how to make the program identify new files since the last time the program was started/closed, because I dont want to monitor the folder the whole time the program is running, but only at the start of the program.

I thought about comparing the files in the 2 folders, but with houndreds of files it would be bad perfomance wise, wouldnt it ?

Besides that if someone knows how to automatically copy files and could give me an idea for it too, that would be great.

Iam very new to vb.net and only have limited experience with coding, so forgive me if I ask some easy questions.

Every idea and answer is much appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: Thank you very much guys for your ideas, gonna test some of these :)

Comment: You could just compare the NUMBER of files in the two folders. If they are different, you have to copy some new ones. Might be easier in terms of performance.

Comment: `but with houndreds of files it would be bad perfomance wise, wouldnt it ?` - Not necessarily. That depends on how you compare them. If you want to check for already existing, but updated, files you could iterate through every file and generate a hash of each, then compare that to the hashes of the files you've already got.

Comment: You could also cache the last time your program started (the time you compared the files) and the next startup copies only the files that are newer than the cached time.

Comment: @WaiYan : A problem with that method would be that the last written/modified/accessed dates can be forged.

Comment: @VisualVincent of course. I'm assuming it is not tampered with in the first place. Comparing the hashes is always safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach.

I use this approach in backing-up my files into our server.

This will check for new files and *newer-dated* version of an existing file (if any) then overwrites it.

I used the `XCopy` command in my `batch file`

Creating `batch files` is pretty much basic.

- Open a Notepad
- Paste this command: `XCopy "C:\YourSourceFolder\*.*"
  "D:\YourDestinationFolder" /D /S /Y`
- Save the file having an extension of `.bat`

Explanation regarding `XCopy`:

- `*.*` specifies that all the files inside your directory will be
  copied.
- `/D` means it copies only those files whose source time is    newer
  than the destination time.
- `/S` will copy directories and sub    directories except empty ones.
- `/Y` overwrites existing files without prompting

Source: [MS-DOS XCopy Command](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm)

Now, running it through `VB.Net` takes only a one line of code. You could put it in a `Button_Click`,`Timer_tick` or any events you prefer.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\YourBatFile.bat")
```

Of course, the directory still varies on where did you saved your `.bat` file.

Source: [Run a batch file in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178872/run-batch-file-in-vb-net)

In your case: You could use a `timer` that executes this `batch file` in an interval of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows service and use a filewatcher https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx